# output from ssh stored in a variable to test its value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

```
  remote_file=$(ssh  -t -o LogLevel=QUIET $ip_address 'if [[ -f ~/logs/output.log ]]; then echo exists; else echo nonexistant; fi')
  echo $remote_file
  if [[ "x$remote_file" == "xexists" ]]
  then
     # do some stuff here
  else
     # do some other stuff here
  fi
```

The variable $remote_file seems to be storing correct value as it prints correct value in the echo statement.  But when I test for its value, there seems to be something wrong as the test always fails and goes to else block.  I tried to debug using `set -x` and noticed that the test condition left side is missing.  What could be the issue here?

`== \x\e\x\i\s\t\s ]]`

Comment: There's no need to use the `"x"` trick when using double brackets.

Comment: Heck, there's no need to use it with single brackets either if you're quoting correctly and  aren't using obsolescent features like `test -a` or `test -o`.

Comment: @vijayanand, ...instead of `echo $remote_file`, run `declare -p remote_file` -- or, even better, `printf 'remote_file=%q\n' "$remote_file"`; either of those will give you a much more accurate idea of the variable's contents.

Comment: There has to be more to the `set -x` output than just that.

Comment: @Tanktalus, if the variable contents have sufficiently interesting terminal/cursor control sequences, maybe not. But using a more effective way than `echo` to check what that variable contains will expose that.

Comment: Yes there would be more output in the set -x but I just added the set -x right after the ssh command and suppressed it with set +x after test, so that it only prints the debug from that test line.

Comment: @vijayanand, please follow up with output from `declare -p remote_file` or `printf 'remote_file=%q\n' "$remote_file"` as requested above.

Comment: I added the printf statement after the echo statement to see the difference.  Here is the output:
+ echo $'xexists\r'
xexists
+ printf 'remote_file=%q\n' ''
remote_file=''
 == \x\e\x\i\s\t\s ]]
+ set +x

Comment: There's your problem -- there's a stray `$'\r'` at the end of the string. If you run `remote_file=${remote_file%$'\r'}` between the `ssh` and the test, you should be fine.

Comment: I already suggested using a parameter expansion above, which will operate internally to the shell. `tr` will eat your exit status, unless you've enabled the `pipefail` option -- you can run `if remote_file=$(ssh ...); then ...; else ...; fi` to branch if your `ssh` fails, but if it's `remote_file=$(ssh ... | tr -d $'\r')`, then that's going to have the exit status of `tr`, which will always be true.

Comment: (context for the parameter expansion approach: [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: BTW, why `ssh -t`? Assigning a TTY for a `test` command seems utterly unnecessary, and potentially prone to causing breakage (if a shell wrongly infers that it's interactive).

Comment: Thanks Charles, yes -t isn't necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Charles Duffy, the output might contain whitespace characters that are not obvious, but that you need to add to the comparison or remove somehow from the variable `$remote_file` before doing the comparison.

Note that the example given doesn't really need a string comparison.
It might not be obvious, but if you start ssh with a command, then when the command is finished, ssh will exit with the same exit code as the command itself. So you can simplify your code to:

```
if ssh -t -o LogLevel=QUIET $ip_address 'test -f ~/logs/output.log'
then
    # do some stuff here
else
    # do some other stuff here
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the script does more than just a command, I simplified the question to show the problem I was having.  Your suggestion will help others who might need just a single command to be run.

Comment: The remote command can be arbitrarily complex and the idea to return results in properly machine-readable form is readily adaptable to more complex return values. This *is* the way to go, or you will need to convince us otherwise (perhaps accept this answer and post a new question where you show the problem you are *actually* trying to solve).